# Why does $(window).on('beforeunload', callback); no longer fire my ajax call in Chrome after updating to 73.0.3683.103?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

In our web application we use an ajax call that's fired at the beforeunload event to track whether a user is still working on a certain piece of information. It roughly looks like this:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    $.ajax({
               async: false,
               url: "../orderInformation/assignOrder",
               data: {
                   orderId: orderId,
                   shouldAssign: false
               }
           });
    console.info("Handled beforeunload");
});
```

This was working fine in Chrome, IE and Firefox, until today. As of Chrome version 73.0.3683.103, the Ajax call is no longer firing, although the rest of the JS in that handler does execute. I.e. the message is printed to the console.

Chrome's developer toolbar does not show the AJAX call being executed in version 73.0.3683.103, and I've confirmed our web server has not received the request either. However, when I run the same code on Chrome 73.0.3683.86, it fires the Ajax request and the web server receives it! I confirmed that this change affects both Mac OS and Windows.

What changed in Chrome 73.0.3683.103 that caused this problem? And/or how do I fix it?

This was brought to our attention by a series of support tickets from our clients, as it negatively affected how our application works. For the first time in my 11-year career as a web application developer, I've had to tell our users to switch to Internet Explorer.

Comment: I'm not sure what changed, but i'm not at all surprised. The correct method for sending this kind of request is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

Comment: Would [beacons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API) help here?

Comment: I will try that immediately. I'll have to add it in addition to beforeunload though, as @KevinB's resource says IE doesn't support it.
Additionally, feedback is appreciated when down-voting.

Comment: I would just do a quick check for the sendBeacon method. If it exists, use it, else fallback to xhr

Comment: I ended up with the following workaround:
`var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = url;
document.body.appendChild(img);`. It still performs *synchronous* ajax call from unload event in chrome 73.0.3683.103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this too. I found a tweet that says support for synchronous xhr has been removed from page dismissal events in Blink, which is the browser engine Chrome uses. This happened in early April. Very likely that Chrome 73.0.3683.103 is running on the version of Blink that has this removed. sendBeacon and fetch keepalive are the new recommended methods of firing ajax on pageunload.

[The tweet in question](https://twitter.com/yoavweiss/status/1115215554753781762)

Answer (score 1):

**My workaround using beacon - *asynchronous* call**

Not an answer, but it is a solution: I used the tips provided in the comments to the question to come up with the following fix. I added this above the existing code, so the existing code is the fallback. Please note that using a beacon will trigger an *asynchronous* call.

```
if (navigator && navigator.sendBeacon) {
    navigator.sendBeacon(url);
    return;
}
```

**Workaround mentioned by Ildar Faizov - *synchronous* call**

I did not test this, but reportedly this works and performs a synchronous ajax call.

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = url;
document.body.appendChild(img);
```